# How to add file extension to tkinter textbox?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, textbox, ide

I'm working on a project where I'm building my own Python IDe. At the moment, I have added a textbox where I can write or edit my script file. In the attached image below, due to the invalidity of a file extension, you can see that the text is plain and uninterpreted. Hence, I would like to know if it would possible to add a file extension to the text box so that whatever I type in the text box shall be treated as a Python script.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with tags.

```
import tkinter as tk

def highlight_python_code(event=None):
    print("'fjnB")
    keywords = ['and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue',
                'def', 'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'False',
                'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import',
                'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'None', 'nonlocal', 'not',
                'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'True', 'try',
                'while', 'with', 'yield',r'["\']([^"\']*)["\']']

    text.tag_remove('keyword', '1.0', 'end')
    for keyword in keywords:
        start = '1.0'
        while True:
            pos = text.search(keyword, start, stopindex='end', regexp = True)
            if not pos:
                break
            end = f'{pos}+{len(keyword)}c'
            text.tag_add('keyword', pos, end)
            start = end

root = tk.Tk()

# Create a Text widget
text = tk.Text(root)

# Configure the tags for Python syntax highlighting
text.tag_configure('keyword', foreground='blue')
text.tag_configure('strings', foreground='green')

# Bind the syntax highlighter function to the <<Modified>> event

text.bind('<KeyRelease>', highlight_python_code)

# Set the syntax highlighting for Python
text.config(
    wrap='word',  # wrap lines at word boundaries
    undo=True,  # enable undo/redo
)

text.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your reply. Yes, it helps at some level.
But there are a few things like it highlights texts which are not a keyword.
For example, in "from tkinter import *", it highlights "in" in tkinter. 
Secondly, is there a way to send an argument to the function highlight_python_code, like a "text" object? So I can use the same function for multiple textboxes.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-highlight-the-current-line-of-a-text-widget-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0):

Providing an file extension won't do anything. If you want the `Text` widget to behave like an IDE with syntax-aware features, you're going to have to write that code yourself or find some external library. For example, [pygments](https://pygments.org/) can help with the syntax highlighting.